# Error in inserting and reading files from a person vector

Tags: c++, vector

I created a person class with instance variables name and age. Then I created a person vector to store persons. I wrote two functions to insert and print the persons in the vector. But I get an error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<person*>::push_back(person&)'
             arr.push_back(p1);
```

Below is my code.

```
vector<person*> arr;

void addPersons(person p1) {
        arr.push_back(p1);
    }

void printPerson () {
 //creating iterator
    vector<person*>::iterator it;

    //printing all elements
    cout << "vector arr elements are: ";
    for (it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

The main function

```
int main() {
    person p1("okoro", 12);

    p1.printPerson();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `vector` containing pointer? `vector<person>` seems fine.

Comment: The vector contained type is ````person*```` so, a pointer. And you pushs back a ````Person````, without the pointer. You should not use pointers. Simply get rid of all the pointer stuff and store "full" persons in the ````vector````.

Comment: Change to `vector<person>`, and then don't be surprised if your code magically starts to work.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, who commented. I have tried removing the pointer but it seems the error shifted to the iterator

Comment: I'm getting a weird: error saying: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
             cout << *it << " ";
                      ^~

Comment: Does your `person` class have an overloaded `operator <<`?  If not, then C++ does not know how to output a `person`.

Answer (score 1):

If the vector can have the ownership of the persons (in the sense of the memory), just use

```
vector<person> arr;
```

As suggested in the comments.

Then your iteration becomes (using c++11 loops):

```
for (const person& p : arr)
    cout << p << " ";
```

By the way, it is a good convention to Capitalize the first letter of types:  **Person**

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback